# Trix WYSIWYG Editor change default rows/vertical height of textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

I read through the [Trix documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#readme) and an answer did not jump out at me for this. It appears that the Trix WYSIWYG editor defaults to 3 displayed rows:

[image: trix before]

Any chance this can be toggled to more rows, for example: 15 or so rows:
[image]

Comment: Did you try adjust the height using CSS?

Comment: hmm, I see it has to do with the css min-height attribute.  I'll keep looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of setting the `min-height` css attribute.  Using javascript, this works if you only have one `trix-editor` on the page:

```
$('trix-editor').css("min-height", "350px");
```

If you have multiple trix editors on the page and you only want to change the default height for that one: what I did is I wrapped the trix editor in a div, set a class on that div, and used `find`:

```
$('.solution-trix-field-wrapper').find($('trix-editor')).css("min-height", "350px");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer: but where would one add this code on a rails 6 project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, but I have solved the different way.

You can be overriding the default CSS like `trix-content` class

```
.trix-content{
    height: 350px;
}
```

you can increase the height using this CSS if you want to use scroll after some depth then `overflow-y: auto;` like

```
.trix-content{
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

after `350px` it will automatically add the scrollbar.

#### Where should I add the code?

Try adding it to your stylesheets/application.scss file (if you're using sass - or equivalent files).

Comment: thank you for your answer: but where would I add this code on a rails 6 project?

Comment: I know this answer is two years old but nonetheless I think it's worth pointing out that OP had issues with .trix-editor, not .trix-content.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 7 I had to override the `min-height` of the `trix-editor` element. Code in `app/assets/stylesheets/actiontext.css`

```
trix-editor {
  min-height: 15em;
}
```